# Create a function that computes the approximation of pi, based on the number of iterations specified

Tags: python-3.x

hint：pi can be computed by 4*(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9- ...).

I have idea to solve this question by using while loop, but I'm confused that, in while loop, how can I save my variable every time when i use if conditional.

Here is my code.

```
def piA(num):
i = 1
pi = 4
while i <= num:
    s = 0
    float(s)
    if i % 2 == 1:
        s = s + (1/(2*i-1))
        print(s)
    elif i % 2 == 0:
        s = s - (1/(2*i-1))
        print(s)
    i += 1
    print(s)
return pi*s
print(piA(2))
```

The result shows:
1.0
1.0
-0.3333333333333333
-0.3333333333333333
-1.3333333333333333

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save the previous variable, just use builtin method `sum()`:

```
def pi(num):
    return 4*sum((1 if i % 2 else -1)*(1 / (2*i - 1)) for i in range(1, num+1))

print(pi(10000))
```

Prints:

```
3.1414926535900345
```

Comment: got it, so except this method, do I have method to save that variable 's'?